# Addon cannot be installed by an error of not be able to modify the needed file

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox4, firefox-addon-sdk

I developed an addon and it run perfectly on my PC. But when I send it to install on our client, it got an error that say something like this "Your addon cannot be installed because Firefox couldn't modify the needed file".

Anyone know what the reason might be?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [bug 636268](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=636268): too long paths to add-on's files. To verify, get the client to create a scratch profile in a directory with a short path, like `C:\temp-profile` and try installing the extension there.

Answer (score 0):

Does client have Windows or UNIX-like system?

Looks like permission problem with Firefox profile folder (it is read-only). Look [here](http://support.mozilla.com/pl/questions/796981) for further details.

Comment: Thanks @jakub.gieryluk! They all have Windows. We cannot tell them to use command line or fix any installation folder to get rid of permission issue. Is there anyway to do it by code? Or any better idea?

Comment: Profile folder in Windows is generally something like `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profilename>` (it is different from installation folder which is usually `C:\Program Files`). Thing to try might be to change permissions of profile folder (right click > Properties > disable 'Read-only'). You can also start Firefox with `firefox.exe -P` which opens profile manager so you can create new profile and specify it's folder. If the problem is with permissions and you can't do anything I suggested, I don't know if you can solve it any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! I tried all above suggestions but I finally found the problem was the app ID in package.json was too long, I changed from **jid0-1Z6ceODTjCn4TmgrrAo3ARAo5J0** to **jid1-EGBMRh2YNRZEIg** and then everything work fine. Someone has this problem then can give it a try.